# Does platform target have performance issues if not specified?

Tags: asp.net-core, build, cpu

By default my solution uses `Any CPU` as the default value of the *Platform target* build option.

I was wondering if this has any performance/memory implications when publishing the project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 = 32bits = Max 4Gb of Memory RAM

x64 = 64bits = Max 17,179,869,184 GB of Memory RAM :)

Its depends of what you are doing, if you need to comunicate with a COM API, the bitness shoud be the same as the API